# Regex - Replace everything attached to an expression, but not the expression itself

Tags: regex

If it matters, I'm working with Python/R for this particular script, but I think this should be a general regex question.

I have something along the format of

```
"_id" : ObjectID("34z83b3853e820x583203"),
```

This happens millions of times in a particular file.  I want to convert all of these to

```
"_id" : "34z83b3853e820x583203",
```

The catch is, I can't just replace any "), with ", as there may be other instances in the file.

Replacing ObjectID(" with " should be trivial.

So essentially, I have to find where there is 15+ character AND numbers mixed, immediately followed by "),

Once found, I need to preserve that string, and just delete the ).

Is there a good way to go about this that I'm missing?  Finding an expression and preserving pieces of it?

My initial impression was to use a lookbehind

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9]{15,}")\)
```

In hopes that this would look for a ) that is proceeded by a string of 15+ alphanumeric characters, however

1) I do not believe this means it has to be alpha AND numeric, just alpha or numeric or both.

2) It's not catching the desired parenthesis regardless.

Comment: Do you want to convert `"_id" : ObjectID("34z83b3853e820x583203"),` to this `"_id" : "34z83b3853e820x583203",`

Answer (score 0):

You can do both steps together (replacing opening `(` and closing parentheses `)`)

Regex: `ObjectID\((\"[a-zA-Z0-9]{15,}\")\)`

- `(\"[a-zA-Z0-9]{15,}\")` is the first capturing group and includes the quotes and the alphanumeric characters between which have a rule of 15 or above like you've mentioned. Since this is the first capturing group it is represented by `$1`
- `ObjectID\(` is the literal `ObjectID` followed by the opening parentheses `\(`
- `\)` is the closing parentheses at the end

Replace with: `$1`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KYV8E0/2/)

Hope this helps!